# How to pay no fees?

Tags: transactions, api, transaction-fees

Is there any API where I can create some addresses and making a transaction beetween them just once a month without paying fees?
Or if you can recommend me somewhere with a fee under 5000 satoshis it would be great.

Comment: So you want to automate / schedule a periodic transaction?

Comment: Yes, but with a fixed percentage, not a fixed amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. However, such a NO FEE transaction with small amount of Bitcoin involved could delay your transaction. Your transaction might stay unconfirmed for a long time.

Here is basic idea to make a no-fee transaction:

Split your one of your unspent_transaction_output into two part. UTXO_1 and UTXO_2

Send UTXO_1 to receiver's address; send UTXO_2 to your own address

Make sure that UTXO_1 + UTXO_2 == your unspent_transaction_output

Follow this link to make a no-fee transaction.
https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#simple-spending

Answer (score 3):

The Blockcypher Microtransaction API is free, they eat the transaction fee's for you if you're looking to send small and free transactions.

http://dev.blockcypher.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a [cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to run [`createrawtransaction`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#createrawtransaction), [`sendrawtransaction`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#sendrawtransaction), etc. commands monthly. Cf. "[Creating, Signing, and Submitting Transactions Based on Unspent Outputs](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/ch03.html#_creating_signing_and_submitting_transactions_based_on_phrase_role_keep_together_unspent_outputs_phrase)" of *[Mastering Bitcoin](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/index.html)*.